# What was Tai cooking in the Digimon movie?

Tags: digimon

In the first movie we can see Tai cooking something yellowish. Does someone knows what kind of food was he making?

Comment: Can you provide a time into the movie? The only time I remember him cooking in the first movie is when it shows an egg sizzling in the pan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might actually be referring to the [omuraisu (rice omelette)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omurice) that Tai cooked for himself, his sister Kari, and Koromon in [Digimon Adventure Episode 21](http://digimon.wikia.com/wiki/Home_Away_From_Home), around the 8:38 mark. It's possible that you mistook that scene for being a part of [the second part of Digimon: The Movie](http://digimon.wikia.com/wiki/Digimon_Adventure:_Our_War_Game!) due to the fact that it takes place in the real world and has a similar washed-out color scheme.

[Here's an album of relevant screenshots from that episode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYMfz.jpg)

However, if you're actually referring to [Digimon: The Movie](http://digimon.wikia.com/wiki/Digimon:_The_Movie), like Eric stated above in the comments, Tai cooks an egg in the [first part of the movie](http://digimon.wikia.com/wiki/Digimon_Adventure_%28Movie%29), around the 7:33 mark. I don't believe there are any other scenes of him cooking anything else for the rest of Digimon: The Movie.

[Here's an album of relevant screenshots from the movie.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN70R.jpg)

Comment: Oops, you're right, it was the first one ^^U Thank you a lot